# Swift 5 Decode JSON from response and discard parent node

Tags: swift, alamofire, decode, swift5, jsondecoder

I would like to decode this JSON using `codingkeys` and `decoder` methods in my Swift code. I would rather just create two data models : `Photos` that contains the page information and the array of type `Photo` and not have to create another type.

I tried different methods given online but couldn't get it to work for this scenario. Can I do this short of doing it manually? My response is decoded automatically on Alamofire side and I would love to keep it that way.

```
{
"photos":
{
    "page": 1,
    "pages": 2234,
    "perpage": 1,
    "total": 223368,
    "photo":
    [
        {
            "id": "51854706028",
            "owner": "193539154@N05",
            "secret": "c09e67936d",
            "server": "65535",
            "farm": 66,
            "title": "Window",
            "ispublic": 1,
            "isfriend": 0,
            "isfamily": 0
        }
    ]
},
"stat": "ok"
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify with your current code? It's unclear what you want to discard.

Comment: {"photos":
. 
I would like to discard this from the top and "stat" from the bottom

Comment: You can use a custom decoding `init(from decoder: Decoder)` to handle such case, but that's work. I'd recommend to use two structs, but make the unwanted one private/"hidden" to higher level methods.

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of situation I think it's best to accept the restrictions of Codable in order to get the benefit of the automatic coding/decoding provided. You could work really hard to find a manual solution and then have to maintain that going forward, but in the end what do you get from doing that?

(Not sure where you've got to with your types, but I would go for three types here: `PhotosResponse` and `Photo`, both conforming to Codable (Decodable if you're only going one way), and then a `PhotosMetadata` type which takes a `PhotosResponse` instance and grabs just the values you need.)